# Can we nest #define and #if in C language?

Tags: c++, c

I want to write the following code but it can't be compiled.

(core code piece)

```
void g();

#define MACRO(x) \
  #if (x == 0) \
    g(); \
  #else \
    h(); \
  #endif

MACRO(0)
```

I think the reason may be that #if and #else must be placed in different lines but #define statement can only have one line. I don't know how can I fix the code. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Update: This question occurs when I want to export a list of functions, each of which has one or more internal implementation. All the implementations may be of best perforamance depending on the parameters. See the code below.

```
void fun_1_algo_1(int x);
void fun_1_algo_2(int x);
void fun_2_algo_1(int x);
void fun_2_algo_2(int x);
// fun_1 and fun_2 both have two implementations.
// If x > 1, algo_1 is faster; otherwise algo_2 is faster
void fun_3_aogo_1(int x);
void fun_4_aogo_1(int x);

#define CHECK(x) .... //check if x is a legal number

#define Export(i) \
void fun_##i(int x) { \
  CHECK(x); \
  #if (i >= 1 && i <= 2) \
    if (x > 1) fun_##i##_algo_1(x); \
    else fun_##i##_algo_2(x); \
  #else \
    fun_##i##_algo_1(x); \
  #endif \
}

Export(1)
Export(2)
Export(3)
Export(4)
```

In this example, I can't change #if to if because fun_3_algo_2(x) is undefined. The exported function will be used as a library.

Comment: The compiler has no idea what `x` is at compile time to conditionally include the code...

Comment: No, it is not possible. A `#define` cannot have an `#if` in it, period. What it is that you're trying to *actually* do. There are solutions for each possible case but they're different.

Comment: See C11 [§6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p3) which says: _The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one…_  That applies to the appearances of `#if` etc in the macro body — they are not treated as preprocessing directives (so they end up as syntax errors).

Comment: Note that it is rarely if ever a good idea to include the semicolon at the end of a macro replacement text.  You should use `g()` rather than `g();` — if the macro were going to work, which it isn't.

Comment: If your question is about C, do not include the C++ tag; if it is about C++, don't include the C tag.  Doing so leads to confusion, such as the answer below which considers the tags more important than the question title.  You don't get good answers if you include the wrong tags.

Comment: sometimes that doesn't work either depends on how macro might be used, one of the tricks to make a statement macro is to wrap meaningful content into  single-iteration loop for macro to work like a statement in relation to flow-control constructs like if, switch, etc.

Comment: I have updated the question and added an example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Aside: what's wrong with `void fun_1(int x) { ... } void fun_2(int x) { ... }` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need the inner test to be a macro?

```
#define MACRO(x)  ((x) == 0 ? g() : h())
```

will give you the behavior you want, and if you call it with a constant

```
MACRO(0)
```

the optimizer will constant fold and dead code eliminate it (so you'll end up with just a single call in the executable.)  The only real drawback of this is that you can call it with a non-constant and it will compile to a test and two calls.

---

If you really need to do this in the preprocessor, you can use various token-pasting tricks to build macros that "evaluate" expressions by defining lots of macros covering every possible combination.  BOOST_PP exists which may do a lot of this for you, or you can define a minimal set that meets your needs.  In your case, something like:

```
#define IF1OR2ELSE_1(T, F)    T
#define IF1OR2ELSE_2(T, F)    T
#define IF1OR2ELSE_3(T, F)    F
#define IF1OR2ELSE_4(T, F)    F
#define IF1OR2ELSE_(I, T, F)  IF1OR2ELSE_##I(T, F)
#define IF1OR2ELSE(I, T, F)   IF1OR2ELSE_(I, T, F)

#define Export(i) \
void fun_##i(int x) { \
  CHECK(x); \
  IF1OR2ELSE(i, \
    if (x > 1) fun_##i##_algo_1(x); \
    else fun_##i##_algo_2(x); , \
    fun_##i##_algo_1(x); \
  ) \
}

Export(1)
Export(2)
Export(3)
Export(4)
```

should do the trick.  The basic idea is that the macro IF1OR2ELSE will expand to either its 2nd or 3rd argument depending on whether the first argument is `1` or `2` -- note that that is a *token* not a value, so something like `1U` is not the same as `1`.

You can generalize the above by building a bunch of helper macros that evaluate expressions (like BOOST_PP does)

```
#define IFELSE_true(T, F)   T
#define IFELSE_false(T, F)  F
#define IFELSE_(C, T, F)    IFELSE_##C(T, F)
#define IFELSE(C, T, F)     IFELSE_(C, T, F)

#define EQ_0_0       true
#define EQ_0_1       false
#define EQ_0_2       false
... many (100s?) of these for many different values
#define EQ_4_4       true
#define EQ_(A,B)     EQ_##A##_##B
#define EQ(A,B)      EQ(A, B)

#define OR_true_true   true
#define OR_true_false  true
#define OR_false_true  true
#define OR_false_false false
#define OR_(A, B)      OR_##A##_##B
#define OR(A, B)       OR_(A, B)
```

now you can use

```
IFELSE(OR(EQ(i,1), EQ(i, 2)),
    ..code for i == 1 or i == 2 ,
    ..code for other cases
)
```

in your macros.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is really complete.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. You could approximate a solution using templates though.

```cpp
// generic template to call h() for all values of x
template<uint32_t x>
struct func_chooser { 
  static inline void f()
    { h(); }
};

// specialise for the zero case (calls g())
template<>
struct func_chooser<0> { 
  static inline void f()
    { g(); }
};

// the macro just defers to the template
#define MACRO(x) \
  func_chooser<x>::f();
```

Comment: Works fine for the tag, but not the title of the question `:)`

Comment: This is a fine answer. OP should not have tagged C++ if they don't want a C++ answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it if the question can't be solved in pure C language.

Comment: I have updated the question, and the condition in 'if' may not be a single number, but always a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use `#if` (or any other preprocessor directive) inside a `#define`. Just use an ordinary `if` and let the compiler optimize out the unused code branch as needed.

```cpp
#define MACRO(x) \
{ \
    if (x == 0) \
        g(); \
    else \
        h(); \
}
#endif

MACRO(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I can't use if instead of #if. I have updated the question.

Comment: @zbh2047 you *can* still use `if`